# Anti-Bad activity protection

Tags: anti-virus

I am rebuilding my PC. Along with the regular 3AM Windows-Update, I think I need the following:

1. Anti-Virus

What other kinds of protection (eg Anti-Spyware) do I need / should I get?

Should I get one of those "Suites" like the ones made by AVG or Avast?

Comment: Those all in one software suites are resource hogs and cause all kinds of issues, stick with a quality AV like Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: Oh, also, don't use Internet Explorer, use Firefox or Chrome browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't think that loading a suite will protect you from everything.

Personally, I would load [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/), and leave it there for active protection.

If you want to do a malware type scan every so often, consider using [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [Spybot Search and Destory](http://www.malwarebytes.org), however I would not install the active component - just use these as scanners.

Comment: That's exactly what i'd suggest. I also might recommend a non IE web browser such as firefox or chrome, with a malware blocking filter, and skeptical computing - the best line of defence against malware is one's own brains.

Comment: SAS is also a good on demand scanner...http://www.superantispyware.com/